# Animating a custom layout from bottom of the screen when clicking on a button in the existing layout in android

Tags: android

In my application, I have an activity where I have one button. When I click on that button, it should show a customized layout from the bottom the screen,keeping parent layout visible. I want to achieve this using animation. Can someone please help me by providing some example code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can simply use **Sliding Drawer** example.Refer Following Link.

http://androidimran.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-slidingdrawer-example.html